# How do I re push all branches in Git? (not just local branches)

Tags: git, github, git-push

I need to "re-push" all branches (not just local branches) from my local clone to my origin (github server).

`git push --all origin` only pushes the branches that I had previously checked out. I want to push all of them, including the ones that I did not check out.

**Why do I need to do this**? Because someone did a `git push -f --mirror` and that removed almost all branches from the server (kept only the person's local branches).

Things that I have tried. **Disclaimer**: On all commands that I would be pushing something to the server I am using `--dry-run` because I want to see the result first.

- `git push --all origin`. Only pushes branches that I had previously checked out.
- Trying with a bare repository:

  - `git clone --bare /path/to/loca/repo /some/path/BareRepo` Create a local bare repository from the local repo.
  - `git remote add origin2 https://github.com/xxx/Repo.git` Adding a new remote on the BareRepo to github.
  - `git push --all origin2` Pushing. Again only pushed branches that I had checked out on the original repository.
- If I checkout a branch that I had never checked out and then run the `push --all origin` I see this branch on the output (--dry-run). So this is the fallback... checkout hundreds of branches. But I am looking for a better approach.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**: Just to clarify. I still have my local clone without the removal of branches. This is what I am trying to use to restore the branches.

Comment: You might have to use the reflog to find the names of the deleted branches and then you could pipe those to git-resurrect (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/git-resurrect.sh).

Comment: @matt: deleting a branch deletes its reflog. Deleting a remote-tracking name deletes its reflog, too. This is a bit ... unfortunate. That's the one argument I know of *against* setting `fetch.prune` to `true` in your person Git config: it makes it hard to recover from this one particular other-person-boneheaded-mistake. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still have `origin/*` remote-tracking names in your local repository, you can do this.  Warning: it's a bit clumsy.  It's probably better to just grab the list of names into a file and edit it, rather than using the `grep -v HEAD` trick.

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname):refs/heads/%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin | 
    grep -v HEAD |
    xargs git push origin
```

(this is really all one line, broken up for posting purpses, though as three lines in sh/bash it should still work too).

The general idea here is to use each of your remote-tracking `refs/remotes/origin/*` references to obtain a hash ID to send to the Git at `origin`, asking it to create or update its correspondingly-named branch.

Some very old versions of Git won't have the fancy `%(refname:lstrip=3)` handling, so it's a good idea to run just the:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname):refs/heads/%(refname:lstrip=3)' refs/remotes/origin
```

part by itself first and verify that it produces the output one would expect, e.g.:

```
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD:refs/heads/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/maint:refs/heads/maint
refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/master
refs/remotes/origin/next:refs/heads/next
refs/remotes/origin/pu:refs/heads/pu
refs/remotes/origin/todo:refs/heads/todo
```

for my Git clone of the Git repository for Git.  Note the extra `HEAD` line, which is why we use `grep -v HEAD`, which is clumsy as it will toss a branch name such as `SHEADWICK`, should you have such a name.

Answer (score 0):

You just actually need these commands in order to push all repos:

```
git clone --bare /path/to/loca/repo /some/path/BareRepo
cd /some/path/BareRepo.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/xxx/Repo.git
```

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't help. The problem here is that the new clone of the local clone copies the local clone's *branch names* (and furthermore converts them to *remote-tracking* names). The OP needs to make use of his lingering remote-tracking names.

Comment: @torek I tried this solution but using ```git clone --mirror``` instead, otherwise I did not see non checked out branches. but tried several times to import to forks and empty repos but still did not import all branches. Funny that on the log I see old remote branches as origin/branch1, etc... but they are not imported on github.

Comment: @matias.g.rodriguez: Right, with `--mirror` the new bare clone would have the same refspecs as the original clone. There's no real point though, as the original clone has the same refspecs.